# asp.net mvc passing dervied type to partial view

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
     public ActionResult CreateAdminItemsViewModel(int Typeid, int FormId)  
    {
        ViewBag.formid = FormId;
        Type instantiationType = null;
        instantiationType = typeof(TextBoxViewModel);

        return PartialView("CreateAdminItemsViewModel", instantiationType);
    }
```

My partial view `CreateAdminItemsViewModel` . 
how can i dynamically pass derived type based on typeid to partialview below?
there is an error in the above code

```
@model BaseViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType())
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: Con you more explain?what mean dynamically ?

Comment: dynamically means i get the derivedtype name from view and that is assigned to the partialview

Comment: you can define your model as dynamic object (@model dynamic)

Answer (score 2):

Define dynamic model for your partialview

```
@model dynamic
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType())
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```